# How to set the default ssh username in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-11, default-settings

I've tried:

### ~/.ssh/config

`User myusername`

and

```
Host *
    User myusername
```

And
`Putty > Connection > Data > Auto-login username` `myusername`

And even setting the value in the registry

Seems to work fine on Windows 10 with the .ssh/config

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I had `User myusername` in `~/.ssh/config.txt` instead of `~/.ssh/config` and didn't realize it because Windows hides extensions by default. Renaming the file to `config` made it work.
I set the private key information via Putty `SSh Connection Auth` that was gen'd

[image]

Comment: I am confused by this answer.  How does that option do what your looking for?

Comment: Because I had `~/.ssh/config.txt` with the contents `User myusername` and it should have been renamed `~/.ssh/config`